# Extracting Items From Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm working with a series of text corpus' and in doing so I need to construct a co-occurrence matrix. I'm currently testing writing and testing my code so every time I run I get a different matrix (since `list(set())` is unordered. I've constructed a sparse matrix using `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix()` and would like to be able to use the coordinates and value generated by that type of construction. I imagine that this would be the fastest and most memory effictient way of doing it. At the moment when I try to access those values I am presented with

```
[<1x16 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, <1x16 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, <1x16 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, <1x16 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, <1x16 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
```

When I `print` the sparse matrix I get the following:

```
  (0, 1)    0.5
  (0, 4)    1.0
  (0, 6)    0.5
  (1, 7)    1.0
  (1, 11)   1.0
  (1, 12)   1.0
  (1, 13)   0.5
  (2, 14)   0.5
   ...
  (15, 6)   1.0
  (15, 9)   0.5
  (15, 15)  3.0
  (15, 0)   2.0
  (15, 1)   0.5
  (15, 6)   0.5
  (15, 14)  1.5
```

I would imagine that retrieving those values as they appear is possible.

For the above example I extract the following instance:

```
row = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
         4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8,
         9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 
         13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 
         15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15]

column = [1, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 0, 4, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 4, 5, 12, 13,
         4, 9, 13, 14, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 2, 4, 12, 13, 0, 14, 
         15, 0, 8, 11, 13, 4, 7, 10, 11, 1, 3, 12, 14, 4, 8, 11, 13, 0, 7, 8, 
         10, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 13, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 12, 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 
         9, 15, 0, 1, 6, 14]

values = [0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 
          1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5,
          0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 1.0, 2.5, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.5,
          1.5, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 2.0, 2.0, 0.5, 4.0, 0.5, 0.5, 
          0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 2.5, 1.0, 
          4.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 3.0, 
          2.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.5]

sps_array = sparse.coo_matrix((values, (row, column)), shape=(16, 16))
```

At the moment I'm able to transform `sps_array` using  `sps_array.toarray`  followed then creating a lists where

```
list1 = list(np.nonzero(sps_array > 0)[0])
list2 = list(np.nonzero(sps_array > 0)[1])
```

and creating the following `for` loop to reconstruct the coordinates

```
index = 0
sps_coordinates = []

for i in range(token_size):
    for j in range(list1_count[i]):
        sps_coordinates.append((list1[index+j], list2[index+j]))
    index += list1_count[i]
```

I retrieve the values by

```
list(sps_array[sps_array > 0]
```

Is there a more efficient way to get those coordinates and values relative to what I have done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a copy-n-paste I construct your `sps_array`:

```
In [2126]: sps_array
Out[2126]: 
<16x16 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 88 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

A `coo` format stores its values in 3 attributes, each an array (derived from the 3 input lists):

```
In [2127]: sps_array.data
Out[2127]: 
array([ 0.5,  1. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  0.5,  0.5,  1. ,  1. ,  0.5,
        0.5,  1. ,  0.5,  1. ,  0.5,  1. ,  0.5,  1. ,  0.5,  0.5,  1. ,
        0.5,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  0.5,  0.5,  1. ,  0.5,  0.5,  1. ,
        1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  1. ,  2.5,  1. ,  3. ,  1. ,  0.5,  1.5,  2. ,
        1. ,  1. ,  2. ,  0.5,  1. ,  0.5,  2. ,  2. ,  0.5,  4. ,  0.5,
        0.5,  0.5,  1. ,  1. ,  0.5,  0.5,  1. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1. ,  0.5,
        0.5,  0.5,  2.5,  1. ,  4. ,  1. ,  1. ,  1.5,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ,
        0.5,  1. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1. ,  0.5,  3. ,  2. ,  0.5,  0.5,  1.5])
In [2128]: sps_array.row
Out[2128]: 
array([ 0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,
        3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,
        6,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9, 10,
       10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13,
       13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15,
       15, 15, 15], dtype=int32)
In [2129]: sps_array.col
Out[2129]: 
array([ 1,  4,  6,  7, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,  0,  4,  9, 12, 13, 14, 15,  4,
        5, 12, 13,  4,  9, 13, 14,  0,  1,  2,  3,  5,  8, 10, 12, 13, 14,
        2,  4, 12, 13,  0, 14, 15,  0,  8, 11, 13,  4,  7, 10, 11,  1,  3,
       12, 14,  4,  8, 11, 13,  0,  7,  8, 10,  0,  1,  2,  4,  5,  9, 13,
        0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  7, 10, 12,  0,  1,  3,  4,  6,  9, 15,  0,
        1,  6, 14], dtype=int32)
```

A sparse matrix has a `nonzero` method, whose code is:

```
    A = self.tocoo()
    nz_mask = A.data != 0
    return (A.row[nz_mask],A.col[nz_mask])
```

It makes sure the matrix is in `coo` format, makes sure there aren't any 'hidden' zeros in the data, and returns the `row` and `col` attributes.

This isn't needed if your matrix is already `coo`, but is needed if the matrix is in `csr` format.

So you don't need to go through the dense `toarray` and `np.nonzero` function.  However the `np.nonzero(sps_array)` does work, because it delegates the task to `sps.array.nonzero()`.

Applying `transpose` to the `nonzero` gives an array that may be what you want:

```
In [2136]: np.transpose(np.nonzero(sps_array))
Out[2136]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 0,  4],
       [ 0,  6],
       [ 1,  7],
       [ 1, 11],
       [ 1, 12],
       ....
```

In fact there is a np function that does just this (for any array) (look at its code or docs):

```
np.argwhere(sps_array)
```

(you don't need to use `nonzero(sps_array>0)` - unless you are worried about negative values.)

Comment: I'm observing bizarre behaviour when attempting to use `.row` or `.col` with a sparse matrix I've created. I'm presented with `AttributeError: row not found`, yet when I try the same for the example above I print out a list. The bevahiour is not present when using `.data` and in every case the values are printed. I've managed to solve this problem by using `np.transpose(np.nonzero(sps_array))`, suggested by @hpaulj, and slicing to generate the appropriate lists of columns and rows.

Comment: I suspect your sparse matrix was not in the `coo` format.  Only that format has the `row` and `col` attributes.  `nonzero` uses `tocoo` to convert its input to coo (if needed).  Feel free to stick with `nonzero`if it is simpler.